# Help with an Emacs Regular Expression

Tags: regex, emacs

I have statements like this all over my code:

```
LogWrite (String1,
          String2,
          L"=======format string======",
          ...
          );
```

I want to change each of these to:

```
LogWrite (String1,
          String2,
          L"format string",
          ...
          );
```

I'm trying to write the regexp required to do this using the Emacs function [query-replace-regexp](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html), but not much success yet. Help please!

---

UPDATE:
1) In case it is not clear, this question is emacs specific.

2) I would like to match the entire code chunk starting from Log... ending at );

3) I used the following reg-exp to match the code chunk:

```
L.*\n.*\n.*==.*;
```

I used re-builder to match this regexp. the \n is used because I found that otherwise emacs would stop matching at the new line. The problem is that I don't know how to select the format string and save it to use it in the replace regexp - hence the ==.* part in the regexp. That needs to be modified to save the format string.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have multiple (or escaped) double quotes in those *format string* lines, you can

```
//replace

L"=+(.*)=+"

//with 

L"\1"
```

Update: Removed the lazy quantifier (thanks @tim). Make sure that the regex is not multiline; the greedy `*` will lead to pretty bad results if `.` matches new lines

Comment: Emacs doesn't support lazy quantifiers, according to regular-expressions.info

Comment: didn't work. I used re-builder to check your expression, but emacs considers ( as a normal character, not a special character. I tried escaping it with a \ but no luck

Answer (score 1):

A great tool to figure out emacs regular expressions is:

```
M-x re-builder
```

A brief description from the documentation:

> When called up `re-builder' attaches
>   itself to the current buffer which
>   becomes its target buffer, where all
>   the matching is done. The active
>   window is split so you have a view on
>   the data while authoring the RE.  If
>   the edited expression is valid the
>   matches in the target buffer are
>   marked automatically with colored
>   overlays (for non-color displays see
>   below) giving you feedback over the
>   extents of the matched (sub)
>   expressions.  The (non-)validity is
>   shown only in the modeline without
>   throwing the errors at you.  If you
>   want to know the reason why RE Builder
>   considers it as invalid call`
>   reb-force-update' ("\C-c\C-u") which
>   should reveal the error.

It comes built into Emacs (since 21)

And for the syntax of Emacs regular expressions, you can read these info pages:

- [Syntax of Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html)
- [Backslash in Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I know of re-builder. I simply don't know enough emacs regexp to write the proper expression in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
/={7}(.*)={6}/\1/
```

this should do.

Comment: It's not by me, but I think it might be because GNU EREs don't support lazy quantifiers.

Comment: @Tim: surely, one who knows that would see that lazy quantifier is not really necessary. my answer is also exactly the same as Amarghosh's, so I don't really think it's a **real** reason.

Comment: thanks, @Tim. But I would still want to hear from those two downvoters.

Comment: +1 to take you back to zero. I've a feeling that I'd be accused of down-voting to gain the edge if I keep silent.

Comment: On a second thought, may be the down voter didn't understand the `/pattern/replace/` syntax.

Comment: for one, /pattern/replace/ syntax isn't an Emacs syntax, and this is specifically an Emacs question; I'm not a down-voter, however.

Comment: @OtherMichael: well OP hasn't posted neither emacs commands nor the regex that he tried (if he did, I'd just correct the regex). I'd imagine the ability to interpret widely used syntax would be in place. I see no need to use emacs here, `sed` command, would be more appropriate and straightforward.

Comment: @silentghost I'm sorry if the question was not clear about specifically using emacs regexp. It's not about getting the job done in this particular case, it's about wanting to learn something so that I can re-apply it elsewhere without having to ask on SO. My problem is that I don't know how to save text to use it in the replace expression since emacs doesn't seem to treat ( as a special character.

Comment: @vedang: i think your real problem is that you're using the wrong tool for the job. If it takes you so long to figure out the simplest of the replacement, may be you should consider finding a more appropriate tool.